# How to change number of rows in a UIPickerView after initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a 3-component UIPickerView where one of the component needs to have a different number of rows depending on the current value of one of the other components.  If I set the number of rows using

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

it sets the number of rows for all the values of the other components.  How can I change it dynamically?

Comment: You use the `component` parameter to determine the count.

Comment: That allows me to select the component for which to set the number of rows.  I need to a different number of rows for each row of a different component, e.g. if component 0 is set to row 1, component 1 has 20 rows; if component 0 is set to row 2, component 1 has 15 rows, etc.

Comment: Right. So return the proper number for a given component based on the selection of the other components.

Answer (score 3):

Simply call the following:

```
[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
```